# ASP.NET - Populate DropDownList from DataList value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I'm working on a wedding website for myself so we can let our guests reserve items from our gift list (which are things we'll be doing on honeymoon) and give us a cheque on the day.

I have a DataList which is retrieving a table from my MSSQL and displaying it on my aspx page. One of the values stored in this table is a quantity.

What I want is the ability to populate a asp:DropDownList with the number of options from the Quantity field then click a button and this adds X of that item to the cart (cart is running fine with button for adding one option). Where I'm struggling is actually getting the dropdown populating. My current train of thought is to have a C# function add new items in a for loop based on the quantity.

Here is what I'm trying

#### aspx

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataKeyField="pKey"  DataSourceID="WeddingDatabase">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Gift"> 
            <!-- Other fields ignored for purpose of quesion -->                  
            Quantity:
            <asp:Label ID="QuantityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>' />
            <br />

            <asp:DropDownList ID="QuantityDropdown" runat="server" />
            <% FillDropdown((int)Eval("Quantity")); %>
            <br />

            <asp:Button ID="Btn" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("pKey") %>' OnCommand="AddToCart" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_9EF896_weddingConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Giftlist] ORDER BY [Title] ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

#### aspx.cs

```
    public void FillDropdown(int inQuantity)
    {
        DropDownList dropdown = this.FindControl("QuantityDropdown") as DropDownList;

        for (int i = 0; i < inQuantity; i++)
        {
            dropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("" + (i+1)));
        }            
    }
```

Right now I'm struggling to even get it to compile. Whilst I know what I want to do it's the code that is getting the upper hand on me here.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution turned out to be to set the DataSource through a C# function passing in the Quantity of that item in the Datalist.

#### aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="QuantityDrop" runat="server" DataSource='<%# FillDropdown((int)Eval("Quantity")) %>' />
```

#### C# (aspx.cs)

```
public ArrayList FillDropdown(int inCount)
{
    ArrayList values = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < inCount; i++)
    {
        values.Add("" + (i + 1)); // increment i and add.
    }

    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you configure another `SqlDataSource` and bind that to your dropdownlist like

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_9EF896_weddingConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT distinct quantity FROM [Giftlist]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:DropDownList DataValueField="quantity" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("quantity") %>'
ID="QuantityDropdown" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
DataTextField="quantity"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Close but I want the Quantity to be the MAXIMUM quantity in the dropdownlist. So if I had Quantity = 10 then the list for that item would be 1..10 and if it was 5 it would be 1..5 not just the distinct quantity's of the whole table.

Comment: @S.Coder, I believe that you probably can figure out yourself.

Comment: Hopefully. I've found this hard because I've decided that this would be my first venture into SQL and ASP. Thanks for all your help! I'll keep digging to work it out.